# How to detect, find and install a missing firmware

Tags: software-installation, wifi, troubleshooting, firmware

#### Context

Today I installed Debian 8 on my HP Pavilion Notebook PC, during the installation (specifically during the network setting up), the the system prompted:

```
Hardware needs non-free firmware to run, missing firmwares are:
- rtlwifi/rtl8188efw.bin
- rtl_nic/rtl8106e-1.fw
```

after the installation the wifi it's not recognized and I think it's missing another FW, because the touchpad doesn't work properly, but that's another story...

I'm not a huge expert on system administration, but I'm in CS so you can be specific.

#### Question

Is there a way to detect which firmwares my system is missing?
Where do I have to look to download firmwares? (well I'm on Debian)
How can I install it? (is there something automatic? or do I have to `make` them?)

---

Can someone explain the best practice to overcome this kind of problems? Maybe taking as example the problem with my wifi, so I can solve it too.

Comment: See also my comment about finding missing firmware: https://serverfault.com/questions/1026598/know-which-firmware-my-linux-kernel-has-loaded-since-booting#comment1505615_1044209

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Obviously, it will be difficult to download software if your network is not working. Debian also creates [non-free installation images](http://cdimage.debian.org/cdimage/unofficial/non-free/cd-including-firmware/). One of these would probably have been better to use for your hardware. If your Ethernet is currently working with a different free driver, then you can get the rest of the firmware that you may need for your hardware as follows.

First, become root with `su -` or `sudo -i`. Then edit the repository configuration file.

```
pico /etc/apt/sources.list
```

For each line beginning with `deb`, add the `non-free` repo at the end of the line.

```
deb http://<domainname>/debian jessie main contrib non-free
```

Save and exit. Refresh the database and install the [non-free drivers](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/firmware-linux-nonfree).

```
apt-get update && apt-get install firmware-linux-nonfree
```

This will also generate a new initial RAM disk (`initrd`) and trigger the use of non-free software. Reboot to use the new `initrd`.

```
reboot
```

You can also get a list of all firmware package names if for some reason you have to install one manually:

```
apt-get install apt-file
apt-file update
apt-file search --package-only /lib/firmware
```

The default, free software installer prompts for the inclusion of non-free drivers, so you could provide the package from a flash drive at that time; or, at post installation, you could download the non-free driver from a different computer, save it on a flash drive, mount the flash drive in the laptop, and then install the package:

```
dpkg -i firmware-realtek.deb
```

These can be found on [packages.debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/firmware-realtek).

Comment: Ok perfect, now I'm writing with my wifi. So after updating the database and installing the non free software, I had to run `apt-get install firmware-realtek` found [here](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/firmware-realtek). Thanks! So basically we added the non-free repository to our apt. Right? So can I remove the non-free line in the sources?

Answer (score 0):

`sudo apt-get install firmware-linux-nonfree` or you can use `apt-cache search realtek` to see if there are specific drivers for your hardware.

Comment: keep guessing;-)